# RegCreateKeyEx and RegOpenKeyEx succeeds but RegSetValueEx fails to set value

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am trying to set value for a test key under HKCR. RegCreateKeyEx successfully creates the test key and RegOpenKeyEx successfully open the key. RegSetValueEx output `ERROR_SUCCESS` but doesn't actually write any values. I have been through all similar questions previously asked and the suggestion was that the key would get created under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. I am on 64-bit win 10 and `testkey` is under HKCR; there is nothing similar under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`. I tried two different `RegSetValueEx` and neither works. What am I doing wrong?

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG lResult;
lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "testKey", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL );
if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    cout<<"Success! Key Created!"<<endl;

lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "testKey", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    cout<<"Success! Key Opened!"<<endl;
    const char info[] = "URL:URITest Link\0";
    lResult = RegSetValueEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,"",0,REG_SZ,(BYTE*) info,strlen(info));
    //lResult = RegSetValueEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,"URL Protocol",0,REG_NONE,NULL,0);
    if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout<<"Success! Value Set!"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<lResult<<endl;

}
```

EDIT: See @Remy Lebeau answer below to see where my code was wrong.

Comment: `ERROR_SUCCESS` As I pointed out in the OP

Comment: You opened the key for *reading* with KEY_READ.  Then you attempt to *write* a value.  But the value type is *none*, you successfully created no value.  None of this makes any sense of course.

Comment: @HansPassant: the code is not calling `RegSetValueEx()` on the `HKEY` that was opened with KEY_READ` access. It is attempting to write directly to the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key (which is a mistake), but maybe the API is accepting it.

Comment: I need to add two strings under `testKey` the default value needs to be `URL:URITest Link` and there needs to be an empty string with the name `URL Protocol`. This is based on [Custom URI Scheme for windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau If what you said is true, then how can I access the `testKey` directly?

Comment: @Icarus: You can create and open `testKey` using `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, but you need to be aware of what that actually does. See my answer below. But your `RegSetValueEx()` call is clearly wrong, it is not actually writing to `testKey` at all, because you are passing the wrong `HKEY` to the first parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to set value for a test key under HKCR. RegCreateKeyEx successfully creates the test key and RegOpenKeyEx successfully open the key. RegSetValueEx output ERROR_SUCCESS but doesn't actually write any values.

You are not passing the `HKEY` handle returned by `RegOpenKeyEx()` to `RegSetValueEx()`.  You need to replace the hard-coded `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` with the `hKey` variable in the first parameter:

```
lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, "URL Protocol", 0, REG_NONE, NULL,0);
```

But, in order for that to work, you also need to change your `RegOpenKeyEx()` call to request `KEY_WRITE` (or at least `KEY_SET_VALUE`) permission.  You are opening the key with `KEY_READ` permission instead. You cannot write to a read-only key:

```
lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "testKey", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey);
```

That being said, you shouldn't be writing to `KEY_CLASSES_ROOT` directly to begin with.  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is not an actual key of its own, it is actually a merged view of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` keys:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx)

[Merged View of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498).aspx

> If you write keys to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, the system stores the information under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes. If you write values to a key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, and the key already exists under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes, the system will store the information there instead of under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.

If you want to register a URI scheme that is accessible to only the current user, save it in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\testKey`:

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG lResult;

lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Classes\\testKey", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "Success! Key Created!" << endl;

    const char info[] = "URL:URITest Link\0";
    lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, "" , 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*) info, sizeof(info));
    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, "URL Protocol", 0, REG_NONE, NULL, 0);
    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "Success! Value Set!" << endl;
    else
        cout << lResult << endl;

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

If you want the URI scheme to be accessible to all users, save it in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\testKey`:

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG lResult;

lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Classes\\testKey", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "Success! Key Created!" << endl;

    const char info[] = "URL:URITest Link\0";
    lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, "" , 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*) info, sizeof(info));
    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, "URL Protocol", 0, REG_NONE, NULL, 0);
    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "Success! Value Set!" << endl;
    else
        cout << lResult << endl;

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Comment: @Icarus: Yes. Also, when saving your values, there is no reason to call `RegCreateKeyEx()` and then `RegOpenKeyEx()` for the same key (especially since you are leaking the `HKEY` from `RegCreateKeyEx()`). Just use the `HKEY` returned by `RegCreateKeyEx()` and pass it to `RegSetValueEx()`. It is not an error to create a key that already exists. I have updated my answer to show these details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I now understand where I was wrong and have fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should pass `hKey` into `RegSetValueEx`

Comment: And open it for write access.

Comment: I tried that. I got error message 2. I believe that means the function couldn't access the key.

Comment: Error 2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, which means it could not find the requested key.